# Network Policy Server error message 'Negotiation failed. No available EAP methods'

Tags: windows-server-2012, wifi, radius

I am trying to change our wireless access points to use RADIUS. I have installed Network Policy Server on a server and pointed our wireless access points RADIUS settings to it.

I have allowed all Domain Users in the policy.

However when a client attempts to connect to the wireless network using the 'Use my Windows account' option (I have also tested manually entering `DOMAIN\user` etc. with the same results) the client shows the error message

> Unable to connect to this network

I have checked the Event Viewer on the server where Network Policy server is installed and this error message is generated each time a client tries to connect

> Negotiation failed. No available EAP methods

Here is a screenshot of the properties of the policy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Putting this out there in case it helps anyone else who is struggling with this same error message as I was.  In my case the underlying issue was that my Windows server had been configured so that TLS version 1.0 and 1.1 were disabled, only TLS 1.2 is allowed.  However NPS was still defaulting to TLS version 1.0.

In my case this had been configured via GPO by our server admins.

I was able to manually set NPS to use TLS 1.2 in the registry, following these instructions:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977292/microsoft-security-advisory-update-for-microsoft-eap-implementation-th

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2195158-enable-tls1-2-in-windows-server-nps

You'll be able to see whether or not this is the problem you're having in a packet capture--look at the Client Hello and Server Hello packets and compare the TLS versions each one is trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

one of these things that you do once a year and forget. Since this is top result I'll leave this here;

So issue for me is that I'm using a self signed server cert to auth meraki 802.1x, PEAP refuses to do any auth with expired cert (and empty subject in actual cert)

it expires once a year and needs renewing (from iis is by far quickest). once new one is in place everything is starting to auth as expected again

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, and maybe you've resolved it or moved onto a different RADIUS server at this point. But for anyone else that comes across this remember to check certificates, even if you are only using username/password a valid certificate must be present on the NPS server. I was getting the exact same messages until I resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

The system may not have the private key for the certificate. You can try to restore it with "certutil -repairstore my ". It worked for me.